# What does "the stable saving truth" in this passage mean?

Tags: meaning

> A computer would wait forever to receive my command but would process it the very moment I hit Enter, no questions asked. No teacher had ever been so patient, yet so responsive. Nowhere else—certainly not at school, and not even at home—had I ever felt so in control. That a perfectly written set of commands would perfectly execute the same operations time and again would come to seem to me—as it did to so many smart, tech-inclined children of the millennium—**the one stable saving truth** of our generation

Answer (score 1):

**Stable** is an adjective with rather a broad meaning dependent upon its context. All of the meanings encompass the idea of the noun in question being resistant to movement or to change of (i) state, (ii) aspect, (iii) position, (iv) variation and/or (v) inherent condition.

The OED describes the etymology of stable(adj.), which is currently valid in its meaning, thus

> The Latin adjective has two primary etymological meanings: (1) with passive force of the suffix, that a person or thing can stand upon, firm as a support or foundation; (2) actively, able to stand, not liable to fall, secure; also (especially of persons) standing one's ground, not to be driven back, steadfast. In figurative uses these senses are often blended. The English word has most of the meanings of the Latin.
>
> 1839   C. Darwin in R. Fitzroy & C. Darwin Narrative of the Surveying Voyages of H.M.S. Adventure & Beagle III. viii. *170   A government, which as yet has never rested on any stable foundation.*

**Saving** is also an adjective (Also OED)

> 1.b. That delivers, rescues, or preserves from danger; that protects or guards from anything undesirable.
>
> *2011   H. Y. Jung Transversal Rationality & Intercultural Texts v. xii. 211   Is there..a saving measure on earth to overcome our human-induced ecological crisis?*

Comment: Okay I might get it now. Thank you so much!